# Problemas con el commit en eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

Estoy intentando hacer un `commit` desde Eclipse pero recibo el siguiente error :

> Commit operation failed
>
> Some of selected resources were not committed. svn: E155004: Commit
>   failed (details follow): svn: E155004: There are unfinished work items
>   in 'C:\Users\melissa_valenzuela\workspace\ApHoldTool'; run 'svn
>   cleanup' first.

Comment: El mensaje de error te dice `run svn cleanup`

Comment: ejecuta primero "svn cleanup" antes de hacer el commit

Comment: Ya lo realize asi, y me sale la misma ventana de error!

Comment: Prueba dando un `run svn update` y luego el que te dicen allí `run svn cleanup`

Comment: sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comentan debes limpiar tu copia local mediante

> `> svn cleanup <path>`

por ejemplo:

> `> svn cleanup C:\Users\melissa_valenzuela\workspace\ApHoldTool`

o desde tu cliente usa la opción "Clean up" o "Cleanup":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya lo realize de las dos maneras y me sigue apareciendo el mismo recuadro